# How do i measure the width of an object given that the distance from the camera(calibrated) to my object is fixed?

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0, opencv

Pardon me for i am completely new to coding. To start with, i am using a library of **Python bindings to OpenCV** for the purpose of this project.

My camera is calibrated for it displayed fish-eye distortion. I have obtained the following values for K and D, the intrinsic camera matrix and distortion matrix respectively:

```
K = [[438.76709 0.00000 338.13894]
[0.00000 440.79169 246.80081]
[0.00000 0.00000 1.00000]]

D = [-0.098034379506 0.054022224927 -0.046172648829 -0.009039512970]

Focal length: 2.8mm
Field of view: 145 degrees (from manual)
```

When i undistort the image and display it, i obtain an image with black pixels at areas which were stretched too far(expected). However, this does not hamper with the calculation of object width since the object isn't large, and fills 20% of the image.

I will be placing the object **10cm from the lens of the camera**. Based on what i have read on the pin-hole camera model, i will require the extrinsic parameters governing the 3D to 2D transformation. However, i am not sure how i am supposed to derive it.

Assuming i have the pixel coordinates of the 2 points (each along the edges between which i would want to measure distance), how do i find the real-world distance between those two points using these derived matrices?

Also, if my rectangular object is not parallel to the principal axis of the camera, is there an algorithm to calculate the width even with such conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the distance between your camera and object is fixed, what you can do is first find out the **pixels distance between the corners** found and then convert it into **millimeter** for your object width using the Pixels-Per-Millimeter Ratio/ Scale factor.

*Algorithm used is Harris Corner Detection* [Harris Corner Detection](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html)

**Capture the frame with the object in it**

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
#Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow('LIVE FRAME!', frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
#Save it to some location
cv2.imwrite('Your location', frame)
```

**Calibrate the Pixels-Per-Millimeter Ratio using a reference object first.**

```
 #Read Image
image = cv2.imread('Location of your previously saved frame with the object in it.')
object_width = input(int("Enter the width of your object: ")
object_height = input(int("Enter the height of your object: ")


#Find Corners
def find_centroids(dst):
    ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst, 0.01 * dst.max(), 255, 0)
    dst = np.uint8(dst)

    # find centroids
    ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
    # define the criteria to stop and refine the corners
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 
                0.001)
    corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids[1:]),(5,5), 
              (-1,-1),criteria)
    return corners

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 5, 3, 0.04)
dst = cv2.dilate(dst, None)

# Get coordinates of the corners.
corners = find_centroids(dst)



for i in range(0, len(corners)):
    print("Pixels found for this object are:",corners[i])
    image[dst>0.1*dst.max()] = [0,0,255]
    cv2.circle(image, (int(corners[i,0]), int(corners[i,1])), 7, (0,255,0), 2)

for corner in corners:
    image[int(corner[1]), int(corner[0])] = [0, 0, 255]


a = len(corners)
print("Number of corners found:",a)

#List to store pixel difference.
distance_pixel = []

#List to store mm distance.
distance_mm = []


    P1 = corners[0]
    P2 = corners[1]
    P3 = corners[2]
    P4 = corners[3]

    P1P2 = cv2.norm(P2-P1)
    P1P3 = cv2.norm(P3-P1)
    P2P4 = cv2.norm(P4-P2)
    P3P4 = cv2.norm(P4-P3)

    pixelsPerMetric_width1 = P1P2 / object_width
    pixelsPerMetric_width2 = P3P4 / object_width
    pixelsPerMetric_height1 = P1P3 / object_height
    pixelsPerMetric_height2 = P2P4 / object_height



    #Average of PixelsPerMetric
    pixelsPerMetric_avg = pixelsPerMetric_width1 + pixelsPerMetric_width2 + pixelsPerMetric_height1 + pixelsPerMetric_height2 

    pixelsPerMetric = pixelsPerMetric_avg / 4
    print(pixelsPerMetric)
    P1P2_mm = P1P2 / pixelsPerMetric
    P1P3_mm = P1P3 / pixelsPerMetric
    P2P4_mm = P2P4 / pixelsPerMetric
    P3P4_mm = P3P4 / pixelsPerMetric

    distance_mm.append(P1P2_mm)
    distance_mm.append(P1P3_mm)
    distance_mm.append(P2P4_mm)
    distance_mm.append(P3P4_mm)

    distance_pixel.append(P1P2)
    distance_pixel.append(P1P3)
    distance_pixel.append(P2P4)
    distance_pixel.append(P3P4)
```

**Print the distance in pixels and mm i.e your width and height**

```
print(distance_pixel)
print(distance_mm)
```

> The `pixelsPerMetric` is your scale factor and gives the average number of pixels per mm. You can modify this code to work accordingly to your needs.

Comment: @VarunMoorthy If it helped, please consider marking this answer as a solution. Furthermore, if you need help, you can ask in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would use similar triangles to determine that the width in the image is proportional to the object width by a scale factor of `(distance of camera to object)/(focal length)` which is `100/2.8` in your case. This would be under the assumption that the object is in the center of the image (i.e directly in front of the camera).